# sql convert error on view tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT logicalTime, traceValue, unitType, entName 
FROM vwSimProjAgentTrace 
WHERE valueType = 10  
AND agentName ='AtisMesafesi' 
AND ( entName = 'Hawk-1') 
AND simName IN ('TipSenaryo1_0') 
AND logicalTime IN (
    SELECT logicalTime 
    FROM vwSimProjAgentTrace 
    WHERE valueType = 10  AND agentName ='AtisIrtifasi' 
    AND ( entName = 'Hawk-1') 
    AND simName IN ('TipSenaryo1_0')  
    AND CONVERT(FLOAT , traceValue) > 123
) ORDER BY simName, logicalTime
```

This is my sql command and table is a view table...
each time i put "convert(float...) part " i get 
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

this error...

Comment: please mention which database you are using.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server.

Comment: SELECT logicalTime 
FROM vwSimProjAgentTrace 
WHERE valueType = 10  
AND agentName ='AtisIrtifasi' 
AND entName = 'Hawk-1' 
AND simName = 'TipSenaryo1_0' 
and CONVERT(FLOAT , traceValue) > 123

This is the inner select part and it gives same error...iam using MSSQL 2005

Comment: @user2409435 : any example of tracevalue ?

Comment: Your tag shows mysql but in your comment `I am using MSQSQL 2005`? Wich one would it be?

Comment: where is this mysql stuff ? i didnt put such a thing..

Comment: traceValue is always sth like 1234.0 this...a float value.

Answer (score 0):

One (or more) of the rows has data in the `traceValue` field that cannot be converted to a float.

Make sure you've used the right combination of dots and commas to signal floating point values, as well as making sure you don't have pure invalid data (text for instance) in that field.

You can try this SQL to find the invalid rows, but there might be cases it won't handle:

```
SELECT * FROM vwSimProjAgentTrace WHERE NOT ISNUMERIC(traceValue)
```

You can find the [documentation of ISNUMERIC here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx).

Comment: I checked isnumeric for float and there is not any nonnumeric data...I am sure that ..and i simplified the querry but still same error : 
select logicaltime from viewTable where convert(float,traceValue) > 123 works greatly but whenever i put and simName='' and entName='' side of convert it crashes. i really didnt understand ? is it because of view table usage ? because ago i was using inner joins and they were working fine but my friends changed them and created this viewtables now - convert crashes

Answer (score 0):

If you look in BoL (books online) at the [convert command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), you see that a nvarchar conversion to float is an implicit conversion. This means that only "float"-able values can be converted into a float. So, every numeric value (that is within the float range) can be converted. A non-numeric value can not be converted, which is quite logical.

Probably you have some non numeric values in your column. You might see them when you run your query without the convert. Look for something like comma vs dot. In a test scenario a comma instead of a dot gave me some problems.

For an example of isnumeric, look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22842/1)